# specify input in function

Tags: r, readxl

How to specify the input to be only numeric class in a function in R?. For example,

```
read_data <- function(file_name, sheet, sample_list = stop("'sample_list' must be provided")){
    ibrary(readxl)
    data = read_excel(file_name, sheet = 2)
    meantritc = sapply(samplelist, function(x)data[grep(x, pattern = data$Source),]$Mean)
    names(data) = sample_list
    return(data)
    }
```

How do if `sheetname` is mentioned instead as `read.xlsx()` requires, it should be able to print a message to provide sheet number intread?

Comment: Please provide more clarification.  `read.xlsx()` is not mentioned anywhere in your function, and it looks like you are setting default of `sheet = 2` in the `read_excel()` function you're using.  Not clear what you're asking exactly.

Comment: I hope my edit makes it clearer.

Comment: If you want dynamic user input, you can use `readline`, but it's unusual to have a user update an input mid-function - I'd recommend Erik's approach of just throwing a useful error message so the user can correct the input and call the function fresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by placing the following within your fucntion:

```
if (is.character(sheet))
{
   stop("Sheet must be a number!")
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Thats sensible. Could you suggest how in this case I can use tryCatch()?

Comment: well, tryCatch is really meant for things like doing X if Y fails.  In this case, it seems like if sheet is a not a number, there's no other alternative for your user but to try and enter an appropriate value.  As such I wouldn't recommend it in this case.  Nevertheless, here's a great SO post on the `tryCatch()` function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-write-trycatch-in-r

Comment: `tryCatch` seems inappropriate here - if you have a backup plan in case something is not a number, maybe use `warning()` instead of `stop` and proceed with your backup plan.

Comment: Thanks @ErikKornet and Gregor for clarifying